# Does sparing or killing an enemy in SC:Blacklist have any influence?

Tags: splinter-cell-blacklist

I am playing Splinter Cell Blacklist and every now and then you have to make a choice if you spare (<kbd>ZL</kbd>) or kill (<kbd>LR</kbd>) an enemy. I'm playing on Wii U, so I do not have to account for the no-kill play-through achievements/trophies. Does sparing or killing an enemy have any influence at all for the game? Is only the cutscene directly after the choice different?